# Troubleshooting servo issue on custom PCB

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, schematics, servo, troubleshooting

There is an issue on my custom ESP32 PCB board. One of its features is to control a very high torque hobby servo motor ([this one](https://futabausa.com/product/hps-aa701/)). The PCB works perfectly with a bench power supply but not with a battery ([this one](https://www.duracelldirect.fr/appareil-photo-numerique/canon/oem-pno/lp-e6n.html)). The board works as intended but as soon as I enable power to the servo (through "Servo_enable"), the battery voltage goes down to 1V (BMS battery security state). Then if I power the board to my bench power supply, the servo is working again. I tried to replace the servo and the battery, nothing changed. It is odd because I tested many times with this battery and the servo was working. Do you see any design mistake on the schematic ?

Edit:
When the C4 capacitor is removed, everything working fine.

Explanations:
Servo power is enabled through a N-MOSFET (Q1) which pulls the gate of a P-MOSFET, to ground. So, power to the servo is controlled through "Servo enable". There is a [SS54-MS](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2110131730_MSKSEMI-SS54-MS_C2902914.pdf) diode to protect Q11 from flyback. There is also a [VEJ222M1ETR-1616](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Aluminum-Electrolytic-Capacitors-SMD_Lelon-VEJ222M1ETR-1616_C249624.html) 2200uF capacitor to help the battery about  transient.
The "Servo enable" pin is controlled through an I2C IO expander (multiplexer). I'm using [this one](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/302/PCAL6416A-1509302.pdf). The I2C is controlled with an [ESP32-WROOM-32UE(16MB)](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-wroom-32e_esp32-wroom-32ue_datasheet_en.pdf).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How much current it draws, when battery goes to 1v

Comment: With or without C4 ?